# how to make a radial line segment using D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to create a line using polar coordinates.

Example:
A line whose centre is at cx=0, cy=0, at an angle of pi/4, but only drawn from a start radius of 4 and end radius of 7.

I could use maths and do the job myself, but d3.js appears to have a [radial line generator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_radial), but I'm finding the documentation hard to grasp, being a d3 noob.

Comment: For specific things like this, you're better off crafting your SVG(?) path directly using the primitives available there.

Comment: Not sure about that! Here's the D3 code for an arc: d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(140).outerRadius(200).startAngle(degToRad(90)).endAngle(degToRad(112.5))  and here's the SVG for just the outer curve of that arc: A200,200,0,0,1,184.7759,76.5367  Not nice hardcoding fractional x,y coords.

Comment: Ok, so you specify a constant angle and radius from data `[4,7]`. I'm assuming you mean polar coordinates and not Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: oops, I got my terminology wrong. Sorry. Will amend

Comment: So have you tried something like `d3.svg.line.radial()([[4,Math.PI/4],[7,Math.PI/4]])`?

Comment: That is exactly what I need. I can then use a 'translate' to move the shape to my real centre coordinates (which won't be 0,0). My problem was that I couldn't interpret the rather terse, example-free wiki documentation. If you could put your comment into an answer, I can mark as answered!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the line generator is relatively straightforward. You can use it with the default options and specify everything in the data like this:

```
 d3.svg.line.radial()([[4,Math.PI/4],[7,Math.PI/4]]);
```

Alternatively, you could only provide the data that changes and everything else as a default:

```
 var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
              .angle(Math.PI/4)
              .radius(function(d) { return d; });
 line([4,7]);
```

Comment: Thanks! The second example looks extremely useful, but I'll have to go back to the "Object-Oriented Javascript" book to get my head around it!